# Splitting a big array into smaller arrays with overlap and of specific length

Tags: python, arrays

I'm a newbie to coding and am trying to code something in Python. Below is the requirement.

I have an array with 15 elements.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

I want to split into to overlapping smaller arrays of length 7. That is

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l2 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
l3 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
etc till
l9 = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: the first step to get it done is to try.

Comment: :) @Tonechas - of all the answers here, I should be thanking you coz that's the one that fit my requirement the best! Unfortunately I don't have enough credits to upvote your answer.. And stackoverflow doesn't allow comments simply thanking an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use this code:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
start = range(len(A) + 1)
stop = start[7:]
L = [A[i:j] for i, j in zip(start, stop)]
```

Demo:

```
In [340]: L
Out[340]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

To access individual lists you just need to index `L` appropriately

```
In [341]: L[0]  #first list
Out[341]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [342]: L[1]  #second list
Out[342]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

In [343]: L[-1]  #last list
Out[343]: [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the list in a `for` loop:

```
>>> A = list(range(1, 16))
>>> for i in range(len(A) - 6):
...     print(A[i:i+7])
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

If you want to assign the sublists to individual variables, it's better to use a list comprehension:

```
L1, L2, ..., L9 = [A[i:i+7] for i in range(len(A) - 6)]
```

Comment: Thanks! but how do I get it into individual arrays like L1, L2 etc?

Answer (score 1):

This little function should do exactly what you want and it handles also cases in which len(array) is not an exact multiple of the lengths of the smaller arrays. Of course, you can input the split-size and the extension of the overlap.

```
def split_overlap(array,size,overlap):
    result = []
    while True:
        if len(array) <= size:
            result.append(array)
            return result
        else:
            result.append(array[:size])
            array = array[size-overlap:]
```

How to use it:

```
array = list(range(10))
print split_overlap(array,4,2)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

array = list(range(11))
print split_overlap(array,4,2)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Your specific case:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
split_overlap(A,7,6)

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `slice` to do this.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
# a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

LENGTH = 7
result = []

if len(a) < LENGTH:
    result.append(a[:])
else:
    for i in range(len(a)-LENGTH+1):
        result.append(a[i:i+LENGTH])

print result
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always a good practise to post your own effort (code) in solving the problem. However you can try my solution and I hope it helps:

```
def overlap_split(array, split_length):
  for i in range(len(array) - split_length):
     print(array[i:i + (split_length + 1)])
```

If you look very closely you'ld notice that I've converted @eugene's code to a function which you can re-use. If you plan to make use of the splits then you will have to store each split in individual arrays i.e. l1, l2 ... ln as demonstrated by @eugene